# Insert muliple dict to mysqldb using mysql

Tags: python-3.x

I have been struggling with this for hours and I feel like crying now as I'm unable to fathom out what is happening.

Here is a simplified version of my data:

> {
> "first_name": {
> "0": "OBELISK",
> "1": "RA"   },    "golongan": {
> "0": 88,
> "1": 99   },    "last_name": {
> "0": "GOD",
> "1": "GOD"   },    "nik": {
> "0": 666679,
> "1": 666678   },    "status_aktif": {
> "0": 1,
> "1": 1   },    "tgl_kerja": {
> "0": "Sat, 20 Nov 2021 16:28:00 GMT",
> "1": "Thu, 25 Nov 2021 16:28:00 GMT"   } }

This is the code I have :

```
app.route('/karyawan-import-excel')
def import_excel():
  # df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\python\coba_read_write_excel\testing.csv')
  df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\xampp\htdocs\python\coba_read_write_excel\testing.xlsx')
  data = df.to_dict()
    
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor(curMysql)
  sql = "INSERT INTO zzz_customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
  val = [
    (data.get('nik'), data.get('first_name'))
    # ('Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'),
    # ('Amy', 'Apple st 652')
  ]    
  cur.executemany(sql, val )
  mysql.connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you have created  by doing `data = df.to_dict()` is a nested dictionary. There's not a straightforward way that I know of to get a data structure like that into a MySQL table.

Instead you can make this small change to that line, as shown below, which will give you a list of dicts -- an easier data structure to work with which you can then insert into a MySQL table.

```
data = df.to_dict('records') # produces list of dicts
```

Then you can "get" -- as you were trying to do -- just the values you want into a list of tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = [ 
    (d['nik'], d['first_name']) for d in data 
]
cur.executemany(sql, list_of_tuples)
# ...
```

This is what `list_of_tuples` should look like:

```
In [11]: list_of_tuples
Out[11]: [(666679, 'OBELISK'), (666678, 'RA')]
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.